# Iframe full height in a wordpress page problems (without scroll bar)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, scrollbar

Am trying to get this code

```
<iframe src="http://www.play-asia.com/paOS-38-19-0,,none,0,0,0,0,trans,000000,left,0,0-49-en-76-5-70-dhf7-6-2-78-2i-90-f8z9-33-iframe_banner-40-6-44-100%2525.html" style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px; border-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; scrolling: vertical; frameborder: 0;" scrolling="vertical" frameborder="0" width="100%25" height="1428"></iframe>
```

To fill the page (height wise) and also without the scroll bar ive tryed and tryed to use css without any luck

Anyone have any ideas how/if I do do this?
Thanks

Comment: Is the `width:"100%25"` a typo?

Comment: No that's how the code came, the width is fine its the height which am having trouble with. Thanks for the reply adding 100% on the height also does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Make the iframe absolutely positioned:

```
iframe { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;}
```

You talk about filling the page height-wise but you have a set height.  You also talk 'without scrollbars' but you have scrolling turned on.  The code above will help your iframe jump out of it's container to fill the page as long as its container is not `position: relative`

Comment: Even when I remove the scrollbars part they still show up, as for absolute position the iframe's size changes far to much to use that, sorry should of said this in the main post. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Try `style="overflow: none;"` as an iframe atribute